# Chamar uma trigger dentro de uma Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, trigger, procedure

Possuo uma stored procedure que faz update em algumas tabelas especificas, umas das tebelas possui uma TRIGGER na qual a edição da mesma so pode ser executada se a TRIGGER estiver DISABLE.

Exemplo de procedure que utilizo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PROCEDURE_TESTE" () IS
BEGIN  
         BEGIN                
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' ALTER TRIGGER TESTE.TRG_UPT_TGFFIN DISABLE';

              --Codigo de Update

         ROLLBACK;
         END;
END;
```

Neste exemplo minha trigger deveria ficar habilitada porem o comando EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ignora meu rollback e desabilita minha TRIGGER.

Existe alguma forma de colocar isso em um bloco de transação na qual obedecesse meu ROLLBACK ?

Comment: Não, o ROLLBACK faz desafazer os comandos de DML, para os comandos de DDL você precisa fazer o "execute" , solução criar outro execute para um ENABLE da trigger , retirar o ROLLBACK ou movê-lo para um EXCEPTION  ... https://www.turtlelearning.pt/manSQL/Oracle/introducao/sql-dml-ddl-dcl.htm ... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

Comment: Nota, uma trigger não é chamada, ela executa conforme um evento em uma tabela/view (groso modo). Leia a documentação se possível.